# IndexOutOfBounds when scrolling in listview with no application code in stack trace

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, indexoutofboundsexception

i found some similar problems, but whatever was pointed out as problem seems to not apply here.
I have a ListView with a MatrixCursor and SimpleCursorAdapter as data provider. Only one list item style and no header or footer or so.
When i scroll in the list fast up and down, then probably only when bouncing to the top of the list sometimes i get an IndexOutOfBounds exception without any of my application code in the stack trace. So i cannot even catch it.
This happens (at least, tested) on Huawei Ideos U8510 / Android 2.3.3 and Acer Iconia Tab A510 / Android 4.1.2.
Any idea how to fix or circumvent appreciated. 
T.i.a.

```
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.MotionEvent.getY(MotionEvent.java:903)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2189)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3486)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1693)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1677)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2257)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1881)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-05 10:17:12.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed it by reimplementing ListView.onTouchEvent(). I thought i'd share the code:

```
public class MyListView extends ListView 
{

    public MyListView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        try { return super.onTouchEvent(ev); }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            Log.w("Catched ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
            return true; // handled
        }       
    }   
}
```

You'll have to use <Your.path.to.MyListView> instead of <ListView> in your layout.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The program is trying to access element from `Array` or `ArrayList` you used to set the adapter of the listView, at a particular index. But the element at that index has not been initialized.

If you are using custom adapter to set the list check what the `getCount()` method in the adapter class returns. It should return the size of the `Array` or `ArrayList`, you used to set the list.

Comment: The cursor is created once from the List and both, list and cursor are not changed thereafter. And it should also happen if scrolling slowly, and, actually, should always happen then, not only sometimes. I've checked it though and size and getCount() match.

Comment: As said, it happens when scroling fast and seemingly only at the top of the list.

Comment: can u pin point the line at which the error occurs. In the log check for an entry after error report like " at yourPackageName.ClassName" double click tht and you will get the line in pgm which has error

Comment: Then it might be because the items are not read from db and loaded into list before you are scrolling down. To avoid this read the Db entries and store them in an ArrayList and then set the list adapter with the list

Comment: as sait in the original question and visible from the stacktrace there is NO line of the App's source in the stacktrace.

Comment: all data is loaded in the creator and nothing added / removed thereafter. it only happens when scrolling fast and/or eventuallay a background thread is doing some work.

Comment: this seems to be a race condition bug in ListView/AbsListView/MotionEvent. idunno. but i have now found several other bug reports at other places incl. Firefox on Android. I'm pretty sure its no error in my code but in Android and i need a way to work around it without reimplementing too much myself...